# Browser-based GUI for a python application

Tags: design, python, web-applications, gui, browser

I want to create a web/browser-based GUI for a command-line python application. The goal is to make use of HTML/JS technologies to create this GUI. As the application itself, it needs to run on Linux and Windows, and the interface will be accessible only from localhost (not exposed to internet). The GUI will contain 5 to 10 pages.

I don't want a traditional desktop GUI that includes HTML/JS, but just a bunch of html files and some kind of controller between those and the application.

I also want to make use of asynchronous programming (ajax like) so I can load and print data in the GUI without refreshing the whole page. I'd probably use jQuery for that and a couple other things.

How would you recommend to design this? Performance is not the key here, I'm rather looking at reliability, portability and simplicity.

I'm thinking of using a lightweight python HTTP server / framework (like [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)) and maybe later a Python templating system (at the begining it will just be a couple pages).

**EDIT:**
I'm looking for ideas/recommendations how to build this, not for alternatives to browser/web-based GUI.

Comment: If its only going to run locally, simplify the whole thing and write the GUI in python.

Comment: I want to make use of some javascript libraries, and I'm used to web development, so it is far easier for me than going for a desktop GUI. I also thought about embedding a modern browser (with https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/ ) but I don't want to rely on an external software, plus it would be too much work for me.

Comment: Dont be intimidated by the idea of making a desktop gui.  I find desktop gui's far easier to produce than HTML based interfaces.

Comment: Although I agree they have strong advantages, this is not what I want to achieve. And as you say, *you* find them easier to produce, but it's not my case. At last, I'm using javascript libs that provide things you don't find in Python GUI frameworks.

Comment: https://github.com/twisted/klein

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @GrandmasterB Who says desktop UIs are "intimidating" or "hard to produce"? They are usually more laborious, more platform-dependent - and for very little added benefit.

Comment: @Eugene I dont know who says that.  I said they are *easier* to make, so he shouldnt be intimidated by stepping outside his realm of comfort, which is the web.

Comment: Again it's not about being intimidated, I have developped many desktop GUI in the past, using Gtk, nCurses, WinForms, .Net and I even made a GUI in x86 assembler using [radasm](http://www.oby.ro/rad_asm/). It's just that it doesn't fit my needs here.

Comment: Why the downvote by the way ?

Answer (score 5):

I am currently trying to do pretty much the same thing. Looks like Python has a server ([SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)) so I trying to make an AngularJS web application that will be interacting with Python server.

Potentially there is a [cefpython](http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/) project that would allow distributing Python applications as standalone programs.

Comment: I saw negative comments about SimpleHTTPServer here on SO, I'd suggest looking for another server (I will probably go for CherryPy but there are many others available). Have you tried CEFPython ? I'm afraid it does not provide the most up-to-date Chromium functionalities but I might be wrong. Using a real browser guarantees a real support, maintenance and active development.

Comment: @ack__ I am currently playing with SimpleHTTPServer - I don't think there are any problems if all you need is a single-session server. I am trying to make do only with the staff from default library to make it easier to install on users systems. I have not yet gotten to a point when I need cefpython - but it should be doable to update CEF there if need be.

Comment: Ok, and which CEF version did you use ? I'm not concerned about the multi-process part, rather by the differences between the Webkit API and Chromium-content API, if any.

Comment: You can just grab binaries from their site. They have a CEFClient app you can use to seed your application. I've also seen a couple of CEF-based product, though they use node.js - https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell and https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit. brackets-shell runs node in a separate process while node-webkit (last time I checked) was doing that in-process. I wonder how hard would it be to replace node with Python app.

Answer (score 3):

Your stated criteria are:

- Reliability
- Portability
- Simplicty

If thats the case, a desktop app is the way to go.  There is no need to throw a web server into the mix.  That will just complicate matters for no actual gain.

Based on the OP's edit - that an HTML-based interface is desired - a possible route might be **[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)**.  This will allow you to create a desktop application that runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac using HTML & Javascript.  It takes an approach somewhat similar to PhoneGap (with the exception that the same embedded browser is used on all platforms).  Node is used to power the Javascript, which provides access to a large number of libraries.  And you have access to the underlying system, allowing you to run the Python-based command line program.

Comment: I'd argue they'd be just has easy, not easier. It's not going to be more reliable because he's not as familiar with pytk whatever. He never said anything about command line.  There is nothing LESS portable about a local server. 

Again if he's making his own controls for example, it will be much harder to develop with an application gui.

Comment: You get a lot of benefits by doing our UI in HTML - that's why Steam, Spotify and others support Chromium Embedded Framework. Adobe Brackets is one interesting example - they have node.js running as a separate process alongside CEF UI process.

Comment: Yes the main benefit is flexibility. You have much less resistance for example to developing new controls, reactive layouts, dynamic page layouts.

Comment: Just to clarify - by doing UI in HTML you get cross-platform modern UI with heavily optimized support for font rendering, GPU-accelerated transitions, etc. There is a huge number of well-maintained libraries and frameworks, tools and such. E.g. one irritating problem I face with doing UI in Java is Retina Macs support. No such problem when running in browsers.

Comment: There are a lot of times when a HTML based UI can make a lot of sense (I have some in the Android store right now).  But an app that primarily wraps a local command line exe is *not* one of those times.  A general rule of thumb is... if you are thinking the solution is to install a local web server because your plain html cant do things on the machine you want it to do, you probably should be making a desktop app.

Comment: @Eugene What do you think is doing that GPU acceleration? its the OS.  Why do you think a desktop app doesnt have that support?  The browser itself *is a desktop app*, and its doing all that.  Besides, dont get sidetracked, I dont think the OP needs GPU acceleration to wrap a command line exe.

Comment: In fact I do, as I explained already I rely on different JS libs, some of them doing graphical stuff that use GPU acceleration. I don't see what the command line tool has to do with this.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I'm pretty sure Eugene meant that you don't have to put any extra work into it, not that a desktop application wouldn't have it.  Which is true.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Browsers do things like this - http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome. Also with the browser you get support for frame-perfect animations and transitions - good luck implementing something like http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/appear with a platform-independent UI toolkit.

Comment: GrandmasterB I am not saying you can't do what browser does. You can. But browsers already have it implemented and heavily optimized (competition is fierce there).

Comment: @Eugene You are getting sidetracked.  He is not writing the next Assasin's Creed.  He's wrapping a command line executable and apparently making some graphics.  You do not need FPU acceleration for that.  Nor do you need to install a local web server for something as trivial as executing a command line program.  I could quite literally open up Delphi and in 30 seconds have a program with a button that runs a command line command.

Comment: @GrandmasterB take a look at that ngDemo I added a link. It is not about fancy graphics - it is about making intuitive and smooth UIs. Can you animate list item insertion in Delphi and make it work on Mac, Windows and Linux with Delphi? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery - try doing this with Delphi on Mac. Or even with Qt.

Comment: Actually, yes, and on Android and iOS.  And it uses accelerated graphics, to boot.

Comment: And while that demo has nifty graphics, they are by no means pushing the limits of graphics.  Do you honestly think there arent graphing and charting libraries like that for desktop apps?

Comment: @GrandmasterB There is no free cross-platform charting libraries of the same quality. And with JS you actually get to choose among several libraries.

Comment: The OP did not specify 'free' as a requirement.  Or any graphics, for that matter.  As I said, you are getting sidetracked.  And if you want to use JS, embed a browser in a desktop app... and then no need for a local web server.  Re-read his criteria, and then explain in your own answer how an HTML interface with local web server is simpler (his criteria) than a single desktop executable.

Comment: @Eugene Actually I plan on using D3 :) And I don't want to go in the pain of creating something similar in a desktop app.

Comment: http://www.steema.com/gallery/charts/20  Nope, nothing like that exists for desktop apps.  Desktop software has several decades worth of a head start in this kind of thing.

Comment: @Grandmaster To be honest I think there's a big difference between those examples and the gallery Eugene quoted previously. In my opinion, web-based GUIs are way more beautiful / modern than desktop based ones.

Comment: @ack__  see my edit - it occurred to me that node-webkit may be better suited for your criteria.  HTML & JS, without the need for a local web server.  AND, access to the underlying system to you can run the command line program.

Answer (score 2):

Options for Python web apps:

- django
- web.py
- werkzeug (w/ or w/o flask)
- twisted
- cherry.py
- raw wsgi
- raw simplehttpserver

Any one of these will work. As far as how you build an app; most of these frameworks have online tutorials. Just follow along and adapt it to fit your needs.